# Is it possible to detect the number of return values of a function in python?

Tags: python, function, output, overloading

I want to write a python function like this:

```
def foo():
   if x:
       return y
   else:
       return y, z
```

Is it possible? If it is possible then how can I detect the number of return values?

Comment: Return a tuple or a list instead?

Comment: Yes I know that, but I want to know if it's possible to do it this way?

Comment: What is the purpose of that? What do you want to do with that data afterwards?

Comment: It is possible and you can check if the return value is of type `tuple`, but this is a very bad practice in programming. Consider returning a consistent number of values, or at least returning always a tuple, by using something like `return (y,)`

Comment: You could try `len` on the returned value, but that might not be useful.  If a function returns one list, or a tuple of two lists, then is `len` useful?  BTW, you say you know that a tuple can be returned, but `return y, z` is returning a tuple, so why the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be easier to modify the function to always return a 2-tuple:

```
def foo():
   if x:
       return y, None
   else:
       return y, z
```

or what I'd do absent compelling reasons why not:

```
def foo( z_default = None):  
   # plug in whatever default makes sense in place of None
   # and the caller can override the default if he wants to
   if x:
       return y, z_default
   else:
       return y, z
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. But when your if condition is false your function will return a tuple with `y` at index 0 and `z` at index 1. You can catch the return values in a tuple variable and check the number of returned values using `len()` function for the tuple.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is highly possible:

```
def foo():
    if x:
        return y
    else:
        return y, z

result = foo()
the_number_of_return_values_of_foo_function = \
        1 if type(result) is not tuple else len(result)
```

Good nights.